# Dependency upgrade along with transitive dependencies

Tags: scala, sbt

I have quite a big Play/Akka project on Scala 2.11 with literally dozens of dependencies, for which we need to migrate to all new stack: newest Play, Akka, Scala etc.

But along the upgrade way, our team constantly facing unexpected issues after certain lib update that another lib has transitive dependency on it, which was evicted and suddenly starting to crash in runtime somewhere in internals. E.g. `play-pac4j` has transitive dependency on Play, which we forgot to upgrade properly after Play upgrade from 2.5 to 2.7.

Question: is there any sbt plugin, which can say in advance which dependencies I need to change to which version version, if I want to update dependency `group % name` from `version-x` to `version-y`?

I'm aware of `sbt-dependency-graph` plugin and we are using, but I want some automation. Meaning: `sbt-dependency-graph` has `whatDependsOn` command, but I don't want to manually verify which version is compatible with transitive dependency i want to go to.

Thank you.

Comment: If your project is on github I think you can use this: https://docs.github.com/en/github/visualizing-repository-data-with-graphs/exploring-the-dependencies-of-a-repository . or with this sbt plugin https://github.com/sbt/sbt-dependency-graph however I think it does not show conflicts...

Comment: @Felipe Thank you, but as I mentioned dependency-graph is not an option for me.

Comment: Wait. I found this manager of conflicts that might be what you want .... https://www.scala-lang.org/2019/10/17/dependency-management.html

Comment: @Felipe seems like more or less what I need. Thanks

Comment: I will test on my project as well. I wanted this feature on the past but didnt have time to test...